# Evaluating $\int_{-3}^{3}\frac{x^8}{1+e^{2x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{-3}^{3}\frac{x^8}{1+e^{2x}}dx$$

I can't find solution for this task, can someone help me?

Comment: What have u tried? what are your thoughts?

Comment: Partial integration, and lose my way out :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Hint.** You may write
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-3}^{3}\frac{x^8}{1+e^{2x}}dx&=\int_{-3}^0\frac{x^8}{1+e^{2x}}dx+\int_0^{3}\frac{x^8}{1+e^{2x}}dx\\\\
&=\int_0^3\frac{x^8}{1+e^{-2x}}dx+\int_0^{3}\frac{x^8}{1+e^{2x}}dx\\\\
&=\int_0^3\frac{e^{2x}x^8}{1+e^{2x}}dx+\int_0^{3}\frac{x^8}{1+e^{2x}}dx\\\\
&=\int_0^3x^8dx
\end{align}
$$ and may conclude easily.

Comment: How did you change the limits in second step? Even/odd function property?

Comment: Wow this is fast answer, i need some help just a little bit, in second row how you can change "a" i "b" like that?  + what happen in last row

Comment: @SasaCvetkovic Let me add some details, thanks!

Comment: @SasaCvetkovic We have, using $u=-x$, $$\int_{-3}^0\frac{x^8}{1+e^{2x}}dx=\int_{3}^0\frac{(-u)^8}{1+e^{-2u}}(-du)= \int_{0}^{3}\frac{u^8}{1+e^{-2u}}du.$$

Comment: Then in third row you multiple and how you got four row?

Comment: @OlivierOloa and then you just sum that... now this is amazing man, do you have some literature for me because this is amazing fast, i realy had trouble with this..Thanks very much man!

Comment: @SasaCvetkovic We have $$\frac{e^{2x}x^8}{1+e^{2x}}+\frac{x^8}{1+e^{2x}}=\frac{(e^{2x}+1)x^8}{(1+e^{2x})}=x^8$$ Thanks!

Comment: @SasaCvetkovic This is a pretty trick which I did not invent. Don't forget it now :). Ok, I will find some references for you.

Comment: @OlivierOloa God bless you! I need to learn this tricks are amazing! Thank you for helping and patience i wish you best!!

Comment: @SasaCvetkovic You may have a look at this reference concerning integrals:http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9780511617041

Comment: @OlivierOloa: I've added an answer providing some info about this technique. And as I can see right now, your last comment points to another highlight regarding interesting integrals! :-)

Answer (score 7):

The answer from @OlivierOloa presents a really cool trick and I'd like to add some information around it. This might help to apply this technique to similar expressions.

> The following holds true. If the integral has the form:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \int_{-a}^{a}\frac{p(x)}{1+q(x)}\,dx
> \end{align*}
>
> with
>
> - $p(x)$ is an *even* function, i.e. $p(x)=p(-x)$
> - $q(x)q(-x) = 1$
>
> then
>
> \begin{align*}
> \int_{-a}^{a}\frac{p(x)}{1+q(x)}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-a}^{a}p(x)\,dx
> \end{align*}

A reasoning is given below. But first let's check our example.

> The current integral is *symmetric* around $x=0$
>
> \begin{align*}
> \int_{-3}^{3}\frac{x^8}{1+e^{2x}}
> \end{align*}
>
> with an even function $p(x)=x^8$ and a function $q(x)=e^{-2x}$ with
>   \begin{align*}
> q(x)q(-x)=e^{-2x}e^{2x}=1
> \end{align*}

Now recall that each function $f(x)$ can be uniquely written as sum of an odd function $f_o(x)$ and of an even function $f_e(x)$, since
 \begin{align*}
 f(x)&=f_o(x)+f_e(x)\\
 f_o(x)&=\frac{1}{2}\left(f(x)-f(-x)\right)\\
 f_e(x)&=\frac{1}{2}\left(f(x)+f(-x)\right)
 \end{align*}

Let's define

\begin{align*}
 f(x)=\frac{p(x)}{1+q(x)}
 \end{align*}
 with $f_e(x)$ it's even and $f_o(x)$ it's odd part.

> Since the integral is *symmetric* around $x=0$ the odd part vanishes and we obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
>  \int_{-a}^{a}f(x)\,dx&=\int_{-a}^{a}f_e(x)\,dx\\
>  &=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-a}^{a}\left(f(x)+f(-x)\right)\,dx\\
>  &=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-a}^{a}\left(\frac{p(x)}{1+q(x)}+\frac{p(-x)}{1+q(-x)}\right)\,dx\\
>  &=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-a}^{a}p(x)\frac{1+q(-x)+1+q(x)}{1+q(x)+q(-x)+q(x)q(-x)}\tag{1}\,dx\\
>  &=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-a}^{a}p(x)\frac{2+q(x)+q(-x)}{2+q(x)+q(-x)}\tag{2}\,dx\\
>  &=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-a}^{a}p(x)\,dx
>  \end{align*}
>
> In (1)  we use the fact that $p(x)$ is even and in (2) we use $q(x)q(-x)=1$.

$$ $$

> In the current  situation we obtain
>    \begin{align*}
>  \int_{-3}^{3}\frac{x^8}{1+e^{-2x}}\,dx&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-3}^{3}\left(\frac{x^8}{1+e^{-2x}}+\frac{x^8}{1+e^{2x}}\right)\,dx\\
>  &=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-3}^{3}x^8\frac{1+e^{2x}+1+e^{-2x}}{1+e^{-2x}+e^{2x}+e^{-2x}e^{2x}}\,dx\\
>  &=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-3}^{3}x^8\frac{2+e^{-2x}+e^{2x}}{2+e^{-2x}+e^{2x}}\,dx\\
>  &=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-3}^{3}x^8\,dx
>  \end{align*}

**Note:** This technique can be found e.g. in *[Inside Interesting Integrals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1493912763)* written by P.J. Nahin.

He applies this technique to the seemingly *complicated* integral

\begin{align*}
 \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\cos(x)}{1+e^{(1/x)}}\,dx
 \end{align*}

which becomes *easy* if you know the trick.

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts! (+1)

Comment: @OlivierOloa: My pleasure!

Answer (score 4):

Using $\displaystyle\int_a^bf(y)\ dy=\int_a^bf(a+b-y)\ dy,$

$$I=\int_{-a}^a\frac{x^{2n}}{1+e^{mx}}dx=\int_{-a}^a\frac{(-a+a-x)^{2n}}{1+e^{m(-a+a-x)}}dx=\int_{-a}^a\dfrac{x^{2n}e^{mx}}{1+e^{mx}}dx$$

$$I+I=\int_{-a}^a\frac{x^{2n}}{1+e^{mx}}dx+\int_{-a}^a\dfrac{x^{2n}e^{mx}}{1+e^{mx}}dx=\int_{-a}^ax^{2n}\ dx=?$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\displaystyle I =\int_{-3}^{3}\frac{x^8}{1+e^{2x}}dx................(1)\;,$$

Now Let $x=-t\;,$ Then $dx = -dt$ and Changing Limit, We get

$$\displaystyle I = -\int_{3}^{-3}\frac{t^8}{1+e^{-2t}}dt = \int_{-3}^{3}\frac{t^8\cdot e^{2t}}{1+e^{2t}}dt = \int_{-3}^{3}\frac{x^{8}\cdot e^{2x}}{1+e^{2x}}dx$$

So $$\displaystyle I = \int_{-3}^{3}\frac{x^{8}\cdot e^{2x}}{1+e^{2x}}dx.................(2)$$

Above we have used $$\displaystyle \bullet \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = -\int_{b}^{a}f(x)dx$$ and the used $$\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt = \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$

So we get $$\displaystyle 2I = \int_{-3}^{3}\frac{x^8\cdot \left(1+e^{2x}\right)}{1+e^{2x}}dx = \int_{-3}^{3}x^8dx = 2\int_{0}^{3}x^8dx = \frac{2\cdot 3^9}{9}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I = \int_{-3}^{3}\frac{x^{8}}{1+e^{2x}}dx = 3^7$$